# Вывод номера первого числа Фибоначчи, кратного N

Tags: c++, математика, числа-фибоначчи

Задача состоит в выводе номера первого числа Фибоначчи, кратного N. Проблема в том, что для некоторых N искомое число Фиббоначи слишком большое, и не укладывается в стандартные типы данных C++(long long). Есть ли способ каким-либо образом оптимизировать работу алгоритма? Входное N не должно быть больше 1000.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А зачем вы пытаетесь вычислить *сами числа* Фибоначчи? Вам достаточно вычислять *остатки* от деления на это число `N`.

```
int fibmod(int N)
{
    int no = 1;
    for(int a = 0, b = 1; b; ++no)
    {
        int c = (a+b)%N;
        a = b; b = c;
    }
    return no;
}
```

Ну, т.е. вычисляем числа по модулю и фиксируем номер числа, пока очередное число не окажется равным нулю - тогда возвращаем этот номер.

Так что метку `большие-числа` я с вопроса сниму - нет тут таких...